# Renamed Core Data Transformable

Tags: objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration, nscoder, nskeyedunarchiver

I'm using `CoreData` to manage my offline storage in my app. The data of the offline storage is saved in an custom `NSObject` as a transformable in the `xcdatamodel`.

My current version in the app (**v1.0**) is storing the `Navigation` class.

I needed to rename the `Navigation` class to fight some name space problems in another target of my code base.

In Version 2.0 the app is crashing because when I'm searching the `CoreData` store the `NSKeyedUnarchiver` is failing because of the missing `Navigation` class.

What's the best approach to migrate my current `CoreData` store to fight this issue?

I tried something like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"OfflineStorage"];
request.fetchLimit = 1;
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"storageID = 1"];

NSError *error;
NSArray *result;
@try {
    result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    if([exception.name isEqualToString:NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException]) {
            NSFetchRequest *deleteRequest = [request copy];
            deleteRequest.resultType = NSManagedObjectIDResultType;
            deleteRequest.includesPropertyValues = NO;
            deleteRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[];

            NSArray *deleteResult = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
            if(deleteResult.count) {
                [context performBlockAndWait:^{
                    [context deleteObject:deleteResult.firstObject];
                    [context save:nil];
                }];
            }
    }
}
```

I though I would be smart to catch the exception and try only to fetch the ObjectID to delete the corrupt data in my store. But it's not working…

Answer (score 1):

Did you add a new version to your model where you renamed that transformable class as well?

Did you try to do your own migration and rename the transformer for the transformable?

Here's some documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH1-SW1

I didn't do that myself, yet. As auto migration was enough for me by now.

**Update**

I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question.

The transformable is transformed by your own value transformer? If so, you could use this in the `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to replace the class with the old name by the new class: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSKeyedUnarchiver/setClass:forClassName:

Comment: I added a new model version. But I think the main problem is that the transformable class itself changed outside of coredata. There is no migration process because the core data thinks its all safe so far. It's only failing after fetching the property :(

Comment: But you set the name of the transformable in Core Data and then register that class for that name. I wonder why the class name is relevant at all.

Comment: I don't register the class name for the transformable. I just drop it there, the rest is done via NSKeyedArchiver

Comment: Sorry, Marius. I forgot to request notifications for updates. So I missed your answer.

Comment: I see, I totally misunderstood your question. Uups!

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSKeyedUnarchiverDelegate_Protocol/ ?

Comment: Or this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSKeyedUnarchiver/setClass:forClassName:

Comment: I will give this a try :)

Comment: The updated answer worked for me. Set the name at app start before loading anything: `[NSKeyedUnarchiver setClass:NewClassName.class forClassName:@"OldClassName"];`